# Using Tuples in TypeScript (Type Inference)

Tags: typescript

Given this slightly artificial example:

```
['List', 'Of', 'Names']
        .map((name, index) => [name, index % 2])
        .map(([name, num]) => );
```

why is name and num in the last line of type `string | number` obviously inferred as an Array of strings and numbers and do any of you know if there is a way to use type inference so that name is a string and num is a number respectively?

Answer (score 17):

You can use a [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions):

```
['List', 'Of', 'Names']
    .map((name, index) => [name, index % 2] as const) // insert `as const` here
    .map(([name, num]) => { }); // name: string, num: number
```

Take a look at the [playground sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/NocgMglgzgLiA0ACEB5AZg5A5AhgWwFMoQBdAKEUsQDo8cAHACkYDt8CkIWATAgDwCUiALwA%20RMDaFOPfogCkiAEwlEOKIgDGAexawhAegOIuUAgCcYiAAbqtu2NcQALCwQpVaDZpPZIWAK54JEJiiADeiAC%20AgDciEaIUgQAXIiw5lwA5v5BaYF4AEYWQA).

Comment: Very elegant! This is especially useful when you want to extend `useState` result in React but keep similar typing, eg adding a side-effect the the function that change the state. The result becomes `readonly` though.

Comment: This should be the answer, given that it is the current way to solve this problem albeit the prior answer does have historical information.

Comment: A downside of this solution is that it produces a readonly tuple. If that's not an issue - works great!

Answer (score 13):

For arrays literals type inference does not infer tuples, it infers arrays, so

```
var foo = ["", 0]; // foo is Array<string | number> not [string, number]
```

I have not found documentation on this but the [pull request](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/428) adding support for tuples never uses inference when declaring them, I'm guessing this is deliberate.

In your case you can specify the type parameter:

```
['List', 'Of', 'Names']
        .map<[string, number]>((name, index) => [name, index % 2])
        .map(([name, num]) => name + "");
```

**2.9 and below solution**

Or create a tuple helper function if this is a common issue for you:

```
function tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5>(data: [T1, T2, T3, T4, T5]) : typeof data
function tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4>(data: [T1, T2, T3, T4]) : typeof data
function tuple<T1, T2, T3>(data: [T1, T2, T3]) : typeof data
function tuple<T1, T2>(data: [T1, T2]) : typeof data
function tuple(data: Array<any>){
    return data;
}

['List', 'Of', 'Names']
        .map((name, index) => tuple([name, index % 2]))
        .map(([name, num]) => name + "");
```

**3.0 Solution**

Since I posted the original answer typescript has improved it's inference with the ability to infer tuple types for rest parameters. See [PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24897) for details. With this feature we can write a shorter version of the `tuple` function :

```
function tuple<T extends any[]> (...data: T){
    return data;
}

['List', 'Of', 'Names']
        .map((name, index) => tuple(name, index % 2))
        .map(([name, num]) => name + "");
```

Comment: Explicit typing is what I wanted to avoid. I could also use an object and use the object destructuring `.map(({name, num}) => ...)` but also not very concise.

Thx for the idea with the tuple func!