# Implicitly create a tuple in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Is there a way without type hinting to create a tuple in Typescript.

If I simply do

```
const tuple = [1, 2];
```

the type of Tuple `number[]`

The closest I can get to a oneliner is

```
const tuple: [number, number] = [1, 2];
```

Am I missing something, or is this the only way?

Comment: your solution will not work with any of indirect changes of the Array, e.g. `tuple.push(123)`

Comment: @Jay tuple itself is a type , if you declare `[number, number]` then you can only push number type in the array. The purpose of declaring an array as tuple is restrict the types of known one or more array elements .

Comment: The only way I know is with a function, this answer is the closest to a solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48872328/infer-tuple-type-instead-of-union-type/48872543#48872543

Comment: Wops, meant this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48686849/using-tuples-in-typescript-type-inference/48687313#48687313

Comment: Awesome answer there @TitianCernicova-Dragomir. Key take away is that typescript can't infer tuples :( Feel free to add this as answer here and I can accept it, given the question there is different to mine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TypeScript 4.0 has an additional way to implictly infer tuple types:

> The type `[...T]`, where `T` is an array-like type parameter, can conveniently be used to indicate a preference for inference of tuple types[:] ([docs](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/39094#Spreads_in_array_literals))

```
const tuple = <T extends unknown[]>(args: [...T]): T => args
tuple(["A", "B"]) // [string, string]
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCuAHANgUxgXhgHgCo1QA8pUwATCGeMAazBAHcwBtAXQD4AKAQwCcBzCAC4YzAHQTcrAJQj8GdjD6CAUAhSpOzAEQBBbQBoY2gELaZMAPSXR0XgEsw-I3cf9WKoA)

Answer (score 24):

With typescript 3.0, you can have your own utility function:

```
const tuple = <T extends any[]>(...args: T): T => args
```

And use it this way:

```
const tup = tuple(1, 2) // tup type is [number, number]
```

Comment: This doesn't work for arrays that have already been created: https://tsplay.dev/w62avw

Comment: @ShaneCallanan The type information is already been lost after the initial array is constructed, typescript cannot magically get the array length back, which is required in tuples. The best typescript can do with the type information it know (`string[]`) is making  `[...string]`, which is effectively a string array

Answer (score 18):

Typescript will not infer tuple types from array literals. You can specify the type explicitly, as you have, or you can create a helper function to make it a bit easier and still get some inference.

```
const tuple = <T extends [any] | any[]>(args: T): T => args
tuple(["A", "B"]) // [string, string]
```

**Edit**

Starting from 3.4 you can also use an `as const` assertion. This does have the advantage of not needing the extra function but it will generate a read-only tuple:

```
var t = [1, ''] as const;
t[0] = 1  //err
```

Starting from 3.0 you can also use tuples in rest parameter to infer tuples:

```
const tuple = <T extends any[]>(...args: T): T => args
tuple("A", "B") // [string, string]
```

Comment: thanks for the details. hopefully in future at least we can use [variadic kinds](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5453) to avoid explicitly declaring many functions

Comment: @Jay I dream of variadic kinds ;)

Comment: Is there a way to do `as const` assertion that return mutable tuple? Something like `[Number()] as MutableConst` which give `[number]` instead of `readonly [number]`

Comment: Just leaving the [link](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27179#issuecomment-422606990) here, in case someone is searching for official docs of `T extends [any] | any[]`...

Comment: `<T extends [] | any[]>` and `<T extends [] | {}>` are shorter and work too.

Answer (score 9):

As of TypeScript 3.4, you can add simply `as const` at the end.

```
const tuple = [1, 2] as const;
```

Full credit to [@bela53](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64035359/80428)'s answer, which has a better example and link to TS playground.

Comment: The behavior is not the expected one since it will prepend `readonly` keywords on every attribute. The other solutions are better.

Answer (score 2):

I am adding this answer for reference as I found it to be a pain that `as const` creates readonly tuples and that other techniques widen the types of the values

```js
const tuple = <T extends any[]>(xs: readonly [...T]): T => xs as T;
```

it can be used in 2 ways:

```
const a = tuple(['foo', 10] as const)
```

`a` is of type `["foo", 10]`, is not readonly and`typeof a[number]` is `"foo" | 10`

---

```
const b = tuple(['foo', 10]);
```

`b` is of type  `[string, number]` and `typeof b[number]` is `string | number`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend defining a type for the tuple because it's more expressive.

```js
type TreeHouse = [location: Location, name: string, capacity: number];
```

and then use

```js
<TreeHouse>[new Location(…), "Treeston", 6]
```

From what I tried this tuple literal cannot use parameter names unfortunately.

Take care of precedence! `<TreeHouse>(…)` has not the same precedence like `new TreeHouse(…)`.