# Typescript keep order or the returned values type in case of mapped object

Tags: typescript, types, iteration, mapping

I'm working on simple mapper of at object. It should accept an array of the object properties and return an array of the values of these properties.
It works fine, but in case of Typescript I couldn't save the type order of the returned values.

Here is the example

```
import { createStore, Store as FriendsStore } from "./mobx_react_lite_store";
import { createAccountsStore, AccountsStoreType } from "./accountsStoreLite";

type RootObj = {
    friendsStore: FriendsStore,
    accountsStore: AccountsStoreType
};

const rootStore: RootObj = {
    friendsStore: friendsStore,
    accountsStore: accountsStore
};

function pickStores<T, K extends keyof T>(rootStore: T, keys: K[]): T[K][] {
    return keys.map((key: K) => {
        const store = rootStore[key];

        if (!store) {
            throw new Error(`Can't find the store with name ${key} in rootStore. Myabe yo've forgottent
            to add this store to the rootStore.`);
        }

        return store;
    }) 
}
```

When I'm trying to call it with only single store, it works like a charm
for ex

```
// Works fine. It shows that accountsStore has AccountsStoreType
const [ accountsStore ] = pickStores(rootStore, ["accountsStore"]);

// Works fine. It shows that accountsStore has friendsStore type
const [ friendsStore ] = pickStores(rootStore, ["friendsStore"]);
```

but when I'm trying to call it with 2 store the returned types don't keep some order.
So `friendsStore` could be EITHER friendsStore or AccountsStoreType. The same for `accountsStore`

```
const [ friendsStore, accountsStore ] = pickStores(rootStore, ["friendsStore", "accountsStore"]);
```

[image: Here is the screenshot]

Is it possible to save the correct **Type** for **each** destructed property?
Thanks for any help.

**UPDATE**
*lukasgeiter* provided the correct answer but there were few interesting tricks for Typescript.  I've investigated them, looked for some documentation etc. and here are the useful resources to understand those features:

Hope this info will help someone.

[About typle](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html)

[Allow deriving from object and intersection types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/13604)

[About lookup types](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/keyof-and-lookup-types-in-typescript)

[About mapped types](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/mapped-types-in-typescript)

Comment: Hi again, I see you posted a second about your problem. I have a somewhat decent solution I would like to post, but I don't know under which question. Please decide which one you would like to keep and delete the other question.

Comment: Alright I've decided to post it here. Please delete the other question. BTW: This solution also works with enums the way you've used them in the previous question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To solve this issue, we have to figure out two things...

### 1. Tuples

To be able to work with the individual types of the elements in the `keys` array we need TypeScript to treat it as a tuple:

Currently TypeScript infers the type of the `keys` argument as:

```js
("friendsStore" | "accountsStore")[]
```

However, what we want is this type:

```js
["friendsStore", "accountsStore"]
```

To accomplish this, there are several solutions:

#### Casting

The simplest, but also most verbose option is to cast the array as tuple:

```js
<["friendsStore", "accountsStore"]>["friendsStore", "accountsStore"]
```

#### Const

Alternatively we can also cast the array as `const`. This will cast it to a `readonly` tuple:

```js
<const>["friendsStore", "accountsStore"] // -> readonly ["friendsStore", "accountsStore"]
```

#### Rest Parameter

If we change `keys` to a rest parameter, TypeScript will infer it's type as tuple. Continue reading to see it in action.

### 2. Mapped Type

Using the correctly typed tuple we can construct a return type which maps the keys to the type from `T`:

```js
{ [I in keyof K]: T[keyof T & K[I]] }
```

- `[I in keyof K]` loops over the elements of the `keys` array. `I` is the index not the element itself.
- `K[I]` gets the type of the element
- `T[keyof T & K[I]]` looks up the type of the property `K[I]` on `T`. I've had to add `keyof T &` in order to satisfy the compiler. If missing it would complain that `K[I]` is not a key of `T`, even though we know that's always the case.

---

### Full Code

I've created two versions of the code which should work for one. One makes use of the rest parameter, the other uses the `const` cast.

Unfortunately I had to introduce an `any` cast inside the function. It might be possible to cast it to something more specific but that's the best I could find.

#### With Rest Parameter

> Note the change in how we call the function because of the rest parameter

```js
function pickStores<T, K extends (keyof T)[]>(rootStore: T, ...keys: K): { [I in keyof K]: T[keyof T & K[I]] } {
    return keys.map((key: keyof T) => {
        // ...
    })  as any;
}

const [ friendsStore, accountsStore ] = pickStores(rootStore, "friendsStore", "accountsStore");
```

#### With Const Cast

```js
function pickStores<T, K extends readonly (keyof T)[]>(rootStore: T, keys: K): { [I in keyof K]: T[keyof T & K[I]] } {
    return keys.map((key: keyof T) => {
        // ...
    })  as any;
}

const [ friendsStore, accountsStore ] = pickStores(rootStore, ["friendsStore", "accountsStore"] as const);
```

Comment: Thank you so much lukasgeiter. It works like a charm, but, to be honest it's some kind of black magic. I though I knew typescript but this is just mindblow.
Could you please tell me where can I read about **tuples casting** and why do we want to have not `(A,B)[]`  but `[A,B]` in this case?
and about this `{ [I in keyof K]: T[keyof T & K[I]] }`. I couldn't understand it naively, unfortunately. I read your explanation few times but I couldn't understand. Maybe there are exists some documentation etc. about this trick? I'd like to understand it.  Thanks for any help

Comment: `(A | B)[]` tells you that each element is either of type `A` or `B`. However we have to know what exact type each element has so we can map it in the same order for the return value. `[A, B]` tells you that the first element is of type `A` and the second of type `B`. The information about tuple casting I have from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49730427/1903366).

Comment: For understanding the mapped type I recommend starting with the [official documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) and then maybe read some blog posts as well. If you have questions after that feel free to drop another comment.