# `as const` alternative to narrow an array literal tuple, to avoid `readonly` modifiers

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

We use `as const` to narrow the types:

```js
[ {foo: 'foo' }, { bar: 'bar' } ] as const
```

but this also adds `readonly` modifiers for all props and values. As of `const` this makes sens, but I would like to have the narrowing, without the `readonly` modifiers, as offen you want to modify the objects in tuple, or just pass it further to some method, which is of the same interface, but without deep `readonly`

```
let foo = [ {foo: 'foo' }, { bar: 'bar' } ]
```

here the foo is of type:

```
({
    foo: string;
    bar?: undefined;
} | {
    bar: string;
    foo?: undefined;
})[]
```

but I would expect to get

```
[{
    foo: string;
}, {
    bar: string;
}]
```

There for we use `as const`, but in most cases it is not possible, as `foo`/`bar` get deeply nested `readonly` modifiers, we could use something like

```
type DeepWritable<T> = { -readonly [P in keyof T]: DeepWritable<T[P]> };
```

But it would be wired to use `as const` which adds `readonly`, and then `DeepWritable` to remove it.

Do you know any alternative to `as const` to narrow the tuple type without having manually to define types.

Comment: How about using [tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) then? It doesn't seem that the only common thing about those arrays you show is that all their elements are one-property objects; and that looks like tuple indeed.

Comment: Those tuples are of predefined types - you do this manually, but I would expect types to be infered from literal declarations - `as const` does exactly this, but additionaly adds `readonly` modifiers which makes it useless in most cases without further casting with some Type Utils.

Comment: Are those [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49729550/implicitly-create-a-tuple-in-typescript) - in particular, `tuple` utility - applicable in your case? I mean, something similar to `let foo = tuple({foo: 'foo' }, { bar: 'bar' })`

Comment: What I actually don't like about this option is the function itself: it _is_ there, in the compiled code, sitting and doing nothing. I suppose that's why the corresponding ticket - https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16656 - is still alive and kicking.

Comment: `tuple` utility is interesting workaround, but as you've mentioned, that stub method in compiled code is not quite good.

Comment: The granularity of `const` type assertions can certainly be problematic but, as its primary purpose is brevity, I think it's a good tradeoff. It sounds like you want a sort of tupleness assertion, which could indeed be useful.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the following generic function to constrain the type as a tuple:

```
const Tuple = <T extends [any, ...any]>(v:T) => v
```

And then wrap the literal:

```
let foo = Tuple([ {foo: 'foo' }, { bar: 'bar' } ]) // foo: [{ foo: string }, { bar: string }]
```

Comment: Though I just noticed that you were discussing similar answers in the comments. I'll leave this here anyway for you to consider.

Comment: Thanks, right, but anyway - this workaround is also quite interesting.

Comment: Cool, `<T extends [any, ...any]>` seems to provide good inference (sometimes I use `T extends ReadonlyArray<any>` but it's more limited).  Do you know any documentation about it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a better generic `Tuple` function, since it preserves tuple member literal values too:

```js
export type Writable<T> = {
  -readonly [K in keyof T]: T[K];
};
export const Tuple = <T extends readonly [unknown, ...unknown[]]>(v: T) =>
  v as Writable<T>;
```

Use it like so:

```js
const foo = Tuple([{foo: 'foo' }, { bar: 'bar' }] as const)
// foo: [{ readonly foo: 'foo' }, { readonly bar: 'bar' }]
// Note the array itself is not readonly, only the object properties are
```

See the [relevant TypeScript 3.4 release note](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#readonly-tuples) for reference.

Also worth checking out this [related, more thorough answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68252190/6283495)