# Use "as const" in Typescript without adding "readonly" modifiers?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

If I want to define a tuple or constant object shape, I'd use `as const`. E.g.:

```
const arr = [{ a: 1 }] as const;

/* readonly [{
  readonly a: 1;
}] */
```

However, I don't want `readonly` because I'd get a lot of `The type 'readonly ...' is 'readonly' and cannot be assigned to the mutable type '...'`

I defined a "Mutable" generic:

```
type Mutable<T> = {
  -readonly [K in keyof T]: Mutable<T[K]>;
}

type Arr = Mutable<typeof arr>;

/* [Mutable<{
    readonly a: 1;
}>] */
```

However, TS doesn't recursively apply `Mutable` in VS Code's type preview. In other words, I want VS Code's type preview to show:

```
/* [{
    a: 1;
}] */
```

I don't think it's possible for VS Code to recursively evaluate `Mutable`, since it could be too slow.

Is there something like `as const`, but without adding `readonly`?

Comment: So what *do* you want? If you're looking for `const arr: [{a: number}] = [{a: 1}];`, then just write that.

Comment: If there's something like as const, but without adding readonly, then that's what I want

Comment: So you want to get the type `[{a: 1}]`?

Comment: Yes, but with a syntax as simple as `as const`. I'm assuming it's not possible

Answer (score 6):

In fact, you already made this array mutable. But you probably have noticed that type of first element is `{a: 1}`

```js
const arr = [{ a: 1 }] as const;

type Mutable<T> = {
    -readonly [K in keyof T]:  Mutable<T[K]>;
}

type Arr = Mutable<typeof arr>[0]; // {a: 1}
```

Because `a` has literal type number `1`, you still can't mutate the element.

Sorry, you can, but you are allowed to use only `1`

```js
const x: Arr = [{ a: 1 }]
x[0].a = 1 // ok
```

In order to make it fully mutable, you should map all literal types to more commont types.

`1` -> `number`

```js
type LiteralToCommon<T extends PropertyKey> =
    T extends number
    ? number : T extends string
    ? string : T extends symbol
    ? symbol : never;

type Mutable<T> = {
    -readonly [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends PropertyKey ? LiteralToCommon<T[K]> : Mutable<T[K]>;
}

const arr = [{ a: 1 }] as const;


type Arr = Mutable<typeof arr>;

const x: Arr = [{ a: 1 }]

x[0].a = 10 // ok
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAMglsCAnAhgGwCoHsDCWC2%20WAdgDwZQQAeixAJgM5QAKSWkSoA0hCAHxQAvACgoYqBWq1GUYgFd8AI2SjxAflkLlSKAC4JlGhHpMGwJHGIBzVWI1mL1vQanGZDEEqxpbUe58VvZ2IIADdkAG5hYVBIKABZOWAURTQIcgFBKABvXwBaJAgUOhI0ECgAbS4oSygAa14sADMJAF19DCrWw2kmVnZkbl4-WARkdGw8QhJyLoF9ROTU9M6uVr4ogF9ogGMSMygUJB0siuzD-QBGKE3ulCY94jMo6NjoAEFjoQSklLTSN7NQ7HDa7fbAKBUfSfE6Vc4oK43VrRKgVAAMrQAdChvpc0VAAPQEqBYOrCIA)

There is an alternative way:

```js
type Mutable<T> = {
    -readonly [K in keyof T]: Mutable<T[K]>;
}

const arr = [{ a: 1 }];

type ImmutableArr = Readonly<typeof arr>

type MutableArr = Mutable<ImmutableArr>

type Arr = Mutable<typeof arr>;

const x: MutableArr = [{ a: 1 }]

x[0].a = 10 // ok
```

You can use just `Readonly` for array. This util will infer `{a: 1}` as `{a: number}`