# What is the difference between these two "extends" clause?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics, tsc

I can't understand why the type of `nVal1` can be inferred on each position, while `nVal2` can't be.

[image]

```
function rSelf1<T extends unknown[] | [unknown]>(vs: T): T {
  return vs;
}

function rSelf2<T extends unknown[]>(vs: T): T {
  return vs;
}

const nVal1 = rSelf1(["a", 1, 2, true]);
const nVal2 = rSelf2(["a", 1, 2, true]);
```

code link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-forked-t1d8o?file=/index.ts

Comment: Try changing the order? Does only the first show again?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Yes, `T extends unknown[] | [unknown]` acts the same as `T extends [unknown] | unknown[]`.

Answer (score 2):

`(A whole bunch of idk the answer but here's some digging I did to maybe give you some context and related info)`

This both baffles me and excites me. Essentially you made me realize "unknown[] | [unknown]" can be used to infer tuples. I always wanted to do this. This does seem hacky and I cant figure out how this works.
I found this [ts-essentials type](https://github.com/krzkaczor/ts-essentials/blob/61f13d12c69d5a2f4d9ece9cd24b9b56c20c2936/lib/types.ts#L416) for tuple. Then I did a little more digging and found this [github reply explaining how this works](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29780#issuecomment-461155157). This helps us a bit. We now know that "unknown[] | [unknown]" forces the complier to infer the tuple type. But why? I dont know that yet. Cant seem to find anything to explain this behavior.

My thought before I did some research on this.
So I cant directly answer your question, but I came across this [related stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48687313/17601830). You can use rest parameters to easily infer tuple types. I like this method because it seems its something the typescript creators intended. But it adds runtime boiler plate and thats not good.

I found this other way(solution 2) to do this, but still not a fully proper solution. With this one you require the user of the function to do "as const" on the array.

```js
// solution 1
function tuple<T extends unknown[]>(...v: T) {
  return v;
}
function rSelf3<T>(vs: T): T {
  return vs;
}
const nVal3 = rSelf3(tuple("a", 1, true));

// solution 2
type Writable<T> = { -readonly [P in keyof T]: T[P] };
function rSelf4<T extends readonly unknown[]>(vs: T): Writable<T> {
  return vs;
}
const nVal4 = rSelf4(["a", 1, true] as const);
```

Comment: I've modified the solution 1 slightly to make it work and concise.
`export type Tuple<T = any> = [T] | T[];`
This definition really inspire me! I can't find anything about this "magic" in official docs but it really work.

So, maybe, the author leave this special grammar to make life simple.

PS: the question initially comes from [the definition of Promise.allSettled](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/lib/lib.es2020.promise.d.ts#L33)